# Paypal recurring split payments

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, paypal, recurring-billing, paypal-adaptive-payments

I have a website where users can subscribe for `10USD` per month to a monthly pack with digital goods. 90% from each subscription goes to the content owner; 10% from each subscription goes to the website owner (the amount is being split). I want to automate this process.

Need to mention that my website is built with Ruby on Rails 3. I already took a look at the gems like [fnando/paypal-recurring](https://github.com/fnando/paypal-recurring), [tc/paypal_adaptive](https://github.com/tc/paypal_adaptive), [jpablobr/active_paypal_adaptive_payment](https://github.com/jpablobr/active_paypal_adaptive_payment) but there's no one particular gem that could help me with my problem.

Any thoughts? Are there useful gems that can solve this problem? Or Web-services?

**Update (June 5, 2012, 17:24):**

I tried to solve the problem using Adaptive Payments but subscription time is limited to one year; On the other hand, Recurring Payments does not support splitting the amount.

Answer (score 2):

PayPal Adaptive Chained and preapproved payments would have been one way.
Another option is to create a normal PayPal recurring payment via Express Checkout Recurring Payments, and then use the MassPay API to send 90% to the content owner, and 10% to the website owner.
The only downside on this solution, is that they are 2 separate transactions, and you will pay fees 2 times.

Did you already check with PayPal whether they are willing to extend the 1-year term for preapproved payments?

Comment: Hi Robert, thanks for your answer! I didn't even tried to contact Paypal, because I've read that it can take couple months before they answer. I'll take a look at the MassPay API, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked out Stripe?

They don't support subscription splitting but they do describe how to go about accepting payments like on a marketplace in their FAQ, see *Does Stripe support businesses that accept payments on behalf of other users like marketplaces?* on https://stripe.com/help/faq

That being said it seems the easiest route would be to take subscription payments and then write an admin portion of your app that takes 10% off the price and prints out checks from your business's bank account, and then send them out monthly.

Another ruby library you may want to checkout is ActiveMerchant. http://activemerchant.org.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately Stripe is still for US-bank account owners (or did I miss somtething?) and I'm in The Netherlands. I'll take a look at ActiveMerchant.